Missing dll error when importing shout module on windows 11
After a lot of research, i finnally installed python-shout on windows 11 without using msys2/mingw.
The setup.py file of the installation module is:
# distutils build script
# To install shout-python, run 'python setup.py install'

from setuptools import setup, Extension
import os
import sys
import setuptools

ver = '0.2.8'


# Define paths to the include and lib directories
iflags = [r'C:/Users/cpapp/OneDrive/Υπολογιστής/mixxx/lib/libshout-idjc/build/include',r'C:/extra/vcpkg-config/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include']
libdirs = [r'C:/Users/cpapp/OneDrive/Υπολογιστής/mixxx/lib/libshout-idjc/build/Debug',r'C:/extra/vcpkg-config/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib']
libsonly=['libssl', 'libcrypto','ws2_32','ogg','vorbis','pthreadVSE3', 'shout'],  # Name of the library without the `lib` prefix

extra_cflags = ['/D_USRDLL', '/D_WINDLL']

shout = Extension('shout', sources = ['shout.c'],
                  include_dirs = iflags,
                  extra_compile_args = [],
                  library_dirs = libdirs,
                  libraries = libsonly)

# data_files = []
setup (name = 'python-shout',
       version = ver,
       description = 'Bindings for libshout 2',
       long_description="""""",
       long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
       url = 'http://icecast.org/download.php',
       author = 'Brendan Cully',
       author_email = 'brendan@xiph.org',
       ext_modules = [shout],
       packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
       classifiers=[
                   "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
                   "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
                   "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2 (GPLv2)",
                   "Operating System :: OS Independent",
               ],

       )

The python setup.py build and python setup.py install run with no error.
But when i try to import the module this happens:
PS C:\Users\cpapp> python
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shout: The specified module could not be found.

I search and download dependency walker.
Then the missing dlls are:
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L3-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PCW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TIMEZONE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-CONIO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-CONVERT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-ENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-FILESYSTEM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-MATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-PROCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-STDIO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-UTILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
LIBCRYPTO-3-X64.DLL
LIBSSL-3-X64.DLL
PTHREADVSE3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-ADVERTISINGID-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-IDENTITY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-7.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-UNLOCK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-MIDLPROXYSTUB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMMANDLINETOARGV-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-MINIDUMP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FEATURESTAGING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LARGEINTEGER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MARSHAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PERFCOUNTERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-RTIMER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRYUSERSPECIFIC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TOOLHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-URL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERRORPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REGISTRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-COREUI-SECRUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-KERNEL32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-7.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-TDH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTLOG-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-DPIINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-HTTP-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-INTERFACECONTEXTS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OOBE-NOTIFICATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-PRIVACY-COREPRIVACYSETTINGSSTORE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CLIPBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-11.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-7.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-9.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SHELL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACCESSHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPABILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTOAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ISOLATEDCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ISOLATIONPOLICY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LOGON-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-ANSI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDLPARSECOND-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SYSTEMFUNCTIONS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-TRUSTEE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-COMHELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-TASKPOOL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-THREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-UNICODEANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-CHANGENOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHDIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STATESEPARATION-HELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
DECLAREDCONFIGURATION.DLL
DMENTERPRISEDIAGNOSTICS.DLL
EDPCSP.DLL
EXT-MS-MF-PAL-L2-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-DEPLOYMENT-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-CACHE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-CACHE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-CACHE-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-6.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-DCOMP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-ORIENTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SHELLCHROMEAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADSI-ACTIVEDS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-MSI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-AEINV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-AEPIC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-APPHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-SHELLEXECUTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-EXT-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-USERCONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-VIEWSCALEFACTOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-BIOMETRICS-WINBIO-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CI-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CI-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CNG-RNG-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-APARTMENTRESTRICTION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-CLBCATQ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-COML2-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-5.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-PSMREGISTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-SUSPENDRESILIENCY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DESKTOPAPPX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DESKTOPAPPX-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DIRECT2D-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DOMAINJOIN-NETJOIN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-DXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-DXCORE-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-GDI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-DXDBHELPER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-DXDBHELPER-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-DXDBHELPER-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DXCORE-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ELS-ELSCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EVENTING-RUNDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FIREWALLAPI-WEBPROXY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GAMING-DEVICEFAMILY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-CLIPPING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-EDGEGDI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-INIT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRINT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-RENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-WCS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-HOSTACTIVITYMANAGER-HAM-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-IMM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-CURRENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MININPUT-INPUTHOST-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MPR-MULTIPLEPROVIDERROUTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MSILTCFG-MSI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WCMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSA-ACTIVEDIRECTORYSERVER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-GUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-GUI-L1-3-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-KEYBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MOUSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-ROTATIONMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWCLASS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWSTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-BINDCTX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OOBE-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PACKAGEVIRTUALIZATIONCONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RAS-RASAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-REINFO-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCEMANAGER-CRM-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCEMANAGER-CRM-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-OBJECT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-INPUT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CURSOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-IAM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-INTEGRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECUR32-TRANSLATENAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-NGC-LOCAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERMGR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERTOKEN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WINSTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WTSAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WTSAPI32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-DIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-EMBEDDEDMODE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELL32-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SMBSHARE-BROWSERCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SXS-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SYSMAIN-PLMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-UI-VIEWMANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-UI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WEVTAPI-EVENTLOG-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WEVTAPI-EVENTLOG-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-DEVICE-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-WIN32BROKER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-SCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WWAN-WWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WWAN-WWAPI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN32-SUBSYSTEM-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WINDOWSCORE-DEVICEINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
FVESKYBACKUP.DLL
LSASRV.DLL
NGCRECOVERY.DLL
POLICYMANAGERPRECHECK.DLL
SAMSRV.DLL
WPAXHOLDER.DLL

While installing i didn't use any dll file, only .lib files.
What can i do?
Edit: I run dumpbin /DEPENDENTS shout.cp311-win_amd64.pyd. It outputs:
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\python_shout-0.2.8-py3.11-win-amd64.egg>dumpbin /DEPENDENTS shout.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.33.31630.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file shout.cp311-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    python311.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    libssl-3-x64.dll
    libcrypto-3-x64.dll
    WS2_32.dll
    pthreadVSE3.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll

  Summary

        3000 .data
        2000 .pdata
       17000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       24000 .text

I search from google to this files and i add it in the same folder with shout.cp311-win_amd64.pyd file.
Now broadcast.py test script stream the mp3 file, i can hear it.
But only when broadcast.py is in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\python_shout-0.2.8-py3.11-win-amd64.egg folder
Edit2: Temporary solution add this path to new system enviroment variable called PYTHONPATH or add new entry to existing PATH variable.
I have uploaded a whl file in github for windows 11 (i think 64bit) and python3.11.4.
Here it is!!
This .whl import the missing dll's automatically and extends the system variable named PYTHONPATH.

I would probably personally consider interfacing with the libshout dll using ctypes rather than wrangle compilation issues...
